# Ruby undefined method '**'

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to write a function that uses array methods to do a variety of things. I need to use the each method to print the cube of each element in the array. Here's my code.

```
def foo(a)

    a.each { |x| puts x ** 3 }

    a.each_slice(3) { |x| puts x }
    a.select do |x|

        if x%5 == 0
            puts x
        end
    end

    a.map { |x| x ** 3 }
    aa.inject(0) { |x, y| x * y }

end

a = Array.new(50)
a.each { |x| x = rand(10..100) }

foo(a)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from task2.rb:21:in `<main>'
        2: from task2.rb:3:in `foo'
        1: from task2.rb:3:in `each'
task2.rb:3:in `block in foo': undefined method `**' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: "...to do a variety of things" is an inadequate and lazy explanation, especially because you have provided no examples. When code is broken, as yours is, you can't expect the reader to be able to figure out what you are trying to do by studying your code. Nor should they be asked to waste time doing that. It's like me pointing to a pile of car parts and saying, "I was trying to fix a few things and the car still won't run. What should I do?".  Please edit your question to explain what you are trying to do and (in addition) give an example that includes desired return values.

Comment: Take a closer look at the error. It says `task2.rb:3`, so the error occurs in line 3: `a.each { |x| puts x ** 3 }`. More specifically it says `**` isn't defined for `nil`, so `x` must be `nil`. And since `x` is an element of `a`, it means `a` contains `nil` elements. Apparently the error's cause lies outside of your method. Something with your array `a` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
a.each { |x| x = rand(10..100) }
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  Each does not alter the original array.  If you want to change the original values of a you need a map!.

```
irb(main):025:0> a = Array.new(50)
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
irb(main):026:0> a.each { |x| x = rand(10..100) }
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
irb(main):027:0> a
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
irb(main):028:0> a.map { |x| x = rand(10..100) }
=> [67, 34, 96, 50, 52, 68, 14, 88, 67, 19, 83, 40, 35, 98, 88, 98, 39, 73, 41, 60, 25, 47, 33, 73, 20, 41, 32, 19, 65, 67, 47, 14, 11, 67, 32, 32, 13, 36, 23, 100, 14, 10, 73, 20, 59, 94, 54, 25, 57, 28]
irb(main):029:0>
a
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

 a.map! { |x| x = rand(10..100) }
=> [97, 83, 52, 54, 22, 54, 39, 32, 42, 70, 84, 15, 69, 32, 28, 40, 50, 98, 66, 79, 25, 37, 97, 28, 30, 11, 98, 57, 73, 77, 99, 75, 72, 40, 67, 62, 87, 41, 58, 10, 88, 24, 98, 10, 31, 94, 53, 43, 98, 17]
irb(main):032:0> a
=> [97, 83, 52, 54, 22, 54, 39, 32, 42, 70, 84, 15, 69, 32, 28, 40, 50, 98, 66, 79, 25, 37, 97, 28, 30, 11, 98, 57, 73, 77, 99, 75, 72, 40, 67, 62, 87, 41, 58, 10, 88, 24, 98, 10, 31, 94, 53, 43, 98, 17]
irb(main):033:0>
```

Also the preferred way to do this is with a range IMO.

Answer (score 2):

`#each` is just a simple iteration, it's doesn't modify the array.
Instead of:

```
a = Array.new(50)
a.each { |x| x = rand(10..100) }
```

you can simply do this:

```
a = Array.new(50) { rand(10..100) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying your array of 50 nil values.  Try `map!` instead.

```
a.map! { |x| x = rand(10..100) }
```

Not sure exactly what the rest of your code is supposed to do but this seems more likely it.

```
def foo(a)
  a.each { |x| puts x ** 3 }
  a.each_slice(3) { |x| puts x }
  a.each do |x| # not sure why you wanted select, does not make sense here
    if x % 5 == 0
      puts x
    end
  end

  a.map { |x| x ** 3 }
   .inject(0) { |x, y| x * y }
end

array = Array.new(50)
array.map! { |x| x = rand(10..100) }

foo(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Ruby `p` method to help you debug things.  (`p x` is a shortcut `puts x.inspect`.)

So try running the following program:

```rb
a = Array.new(50)
a.each { |x| x = rand(10..100) }
p a
```

From the output of that program, you can see that your array just consists of 50 nils.  So then your real question is: How do I initialize an array properly?  The `x` argument to your block is not some kind of reference to a cell in the array, it is simply a copy of the value that was held in the array, so writing to `x` does not do anything to the array.

The simplest way that would work for your application is:

```rb
a = Array.new(50) { rand(10..100) }
```

You could also write it like this:

```rb
a = 50.times.map { rand(10..100) }
```

You could also initialize your array in a more manual way by appending to it 50 times:

```rb
a = []
50.times { a << rand(10..100) }
```

You could also use the `[]=` method, which is the most general way to write to an array:

```rb
a = []
50.times { |i| a[i] = rand(10..100) }
```

It's worthwhile to know about each of these different ways to make an array.